# After joining tables with zend framework , it just show me one tables field

Tags: join, zend-framework, field, show

I have 2 tables `product_category` and `product_sub_category`

The names of the fields are identical (id,name,explain,priority)

`product_sub_category` has an foreign key to the `product_category` table with as `product_category_id`.

With the code below all I see is `product_category` fields

```
$select = $this->select("t1.* , t2.*")
  ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
  ->from(array("t1"=>$this->_name))
  ->joinInner(array("t2"=>'product_category'), 't2.id = t1.product_category_id')
  ->order(array('t1.priority'));
$res = $this->fetchAll($select);
return $res;
```

In `$this->_name` variable should be a string `product_sub_category`.

Why can I not see all fields from both tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL will return the fields with the same name, so when ZF converts them to an array using the name as the index, the latter will overwrite the first. You'll need to give them aliases instead:

```
$this->select("t1.name AS category_name, t1.explain AS category_explain, t2.name AS subcategory_name")
```

and so on.